# How do I install programming info pages in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, unix, c

I used to have a Linux system i was able to type `info libc` to view info pages on the C library, including unix functions. However, now I am running Mac OS X this does not work.

How do I install the libc info pages in  Mac OS X so that i can type `info libc`? Similarly, how do I install section 3 of man pages for access C docs?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe running commands like `info libc` in Mac OS X won’t work by default. But they should work if you install Apple’s Xcode developer tools and make sure to install the command line tools that come with it.